# Android- Chat application - Convert editbox emoticons in string ;) format to save in database

Tags: android, chat, emoji, emoticons

I have developed a **chat application** in android and I want to add the **Emoctions** feature with my application. Till now i have implement this feature with gridview, in which when i enter emoji with text it **appears in editText**. but what i want to save this in **database with :) formate**. Hv created mapping of image & :) string But cant get how to save by changing it.

For edittext i hv used following code:

```
    ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(emojis.images[index]);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return d;
        }
    };
    cs = Html.fromHtml(
            "<img src ='"
                    + getResources().getDrawable(emojis.images[index])
                    + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
    writeboard.setText(cs);
```

**Plz help me to perform database saving and showing it in textview.**
Thanks.

Comment: Hey i ran into similar problem , did you find any solution?

Comment: am creating own Smiley image..  in that case how should i convert the image as string to show in text box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answser by spannable method.

With in spanable method i am comparing string with pattern so whenever that pattern matches in text, it will show emoji of relavent pattern.

I called this method when ever i selected emoji from gridview, on msg recieved, and ontextchanged so whenever it found pattern it will changed to emoji. so like this  it is saving data in text formate of :) and showing emoji as icon.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I am facing above issue now. Can you please post your code here or any reference to the example